# Установка приложения. Установка необходимых компонентов без интернета

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, установка, развертывание

Я написал приложение на WPF и теперь хочу его установить на другой компьютер. Чтобы установить приложение нужно использовать установщик.

Какой установщик нужно использовать, чтобы он мог установить на компьютер необходимые компоненты для работы приложения **не скачивая их с интернета**? Например: .NET Framework 3.5 и т.п.

Comment: Любой? Вроде как любой позволяет установить доп. софт.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте воспользоваться NSIS или Inno Setup, и при установке файлов сделайте проверку на Net Framework определённой версии если нету, то он запустит установщик Net, который необходимо скачать и запаковать в свой установщик, так-же можно свой написать, к примеру на C++, а не использовать NSIS или Inno Setup.