# Как установить проверку на наличие .NET 3.5 и установку его без наличия интернета в Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, visual-studio, установка

Написал wpf-приложение. Пробовал для создания установщика Click-Once в VisualStudio. Установил зависимость от наличия .NET 3.5. Все работает, но установщик приложения скачивает .NET 3.5-installer с интернета. А я хочу, чтобы **если на компьютере не установлен .NET 3.5, он мог установиться без интернета**. Как это сделать?

Comment: Чтобы могу установиться без интернета? То есть, вы хотите установщик добавить в дистрибутив? Почему 3.5? Ему уже больше 11 лет. Для установки без интернета нужен [оффлайн установщик](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5007). Весит 250 мегабайт, меньше точно не получится. А как его встроить в ClickOnce инсталлер, я не имею такого опыта, может кто-то другой подскажет. Есть еще `.NET Core 3.1`, современный фреймворк от Microsoft. На базе него можно делать приложения, не требующие установки фреймворков в принципе, у меня проект в 160 мегабайт собирается в таком режиме.

Comment: Есть еще такой [совет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1092581/Установка-приложения-Установка-необходимых-компонентов-без-интернета).